# BWA alignment "fail to locate the index files"

Tags: indexing, bioinformatics, genome, sequence-alignment

This question has been asked previously, but unfortunately for me the solutions posted did not resolve my issue. I am trying to use BWA to align my ddradseq paired end reads to a reference genome, and keep running into the issue of the program throwing the error  **[E::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] fail to locate the index files**.

This is the code I am using:

```
# Load the BWA module:

module load bwa

bwa mem -t 2 genome/genome.fasta \ processrad_out/sample1.1.fq.gz processrad_out/sample1.2.fq.gz \
>bwa_out/sample1.sam
```

My data it stored in the 'processrad_out' directory, indexed genome in the 'genome' directory, and I want the output to be stored in the 'bwa_out' directory.

I have already indexed the genome, and have tried running my script in the indexed genome directly, but still seem to have the same issue. These are the indexed files I have:

```
LeachsGenome.fasta      
LeachsGenome.fasta.ann  
LeachsGenome.fasta.fai  
LeachsGenome.fasta.sa  
LeachsGenome.fasta.amb  
LeachsGenome.fasta.bwt  
LeachsGenome.fasta.pac
```

Previously when I indexed I was missing the .fai file but managed to correct that issue. Despite, the program is still having difficulty locating the indexed files. I have also tried re-indexing as that seems to have worked for some people but no such luck. I know my paths are correct and I can quite figure out what the correct solution is.

I am fairly new to bioinformatics and am trying to learn as much as I can. Any suggestions are welcome and highly appriciated!

Comment: This type of question is much better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ and will likely be closed here, as it's not ['on topic'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If your fasta file is called LeachsGenome.fasta, that's what you need to use in the bwa command, not genome.fasta.